# How to uninstall old OSGI bundle version upon installation of a new version?

Tags: maven, osgi, aem, sling

I am using the [CQ Blueprints maven archetype](http://www.cqblueprints.com/tipsandtricks/build-and-deploy-osgi/build-deploy-osgi-1.html) for Adobe CQ to deploy OSGi bundles into CQ5.6.1. This archetype uses the [Maven Sling Plugin](http://sling.apache.org/site/sling.html) to deploy the bundles by copying them into an install directory of my content repository. 
I am changing the version numbers of my bundles upon every build using the maven versions plugin. Therefore, upon each deployment, a bundle jar with a new filename is installed, like `commons-services-1.0.30.jar`. My problem is, currently the older bundle versions, like `commons-services-1.0.29.jar`, are not removed upon installation of a newer version.
I would like to avoid old bundle versions piling up in my install folders. Therefore my question is: What is the best way to uninstall/delete these older versions upon installation of a new version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by configuring the filter.xml in my myproject-all module (see [CQBlueprints description for the purpose of this module](http://www.cqblueprints.com/setup/maven.html)) to delete the contents of my bundle install folder. This way, old bundles are always deleted before new bundles are installed.

To delete the contents of my install folder, I added the following line to my filter.xml file:

```
<filter root="/apps/myapp/install">
```

Answer (score 2):

Bundles piling up in an install folder are not really a problem - they will only use the space, but they are ignored by the Apache Sling OSGI installer that CQ uses to detect and install the bundles. The installer only considers the latest version of the bundle (based on its OSGi version header), and ignores older versions.

If you really want to remove the older bundle files, best is probably to create a small tool that finds them by walking the JCR tree under which they are installed (/apps I assume), and delete all but the latest version. If the bundle filenames consistently include the version number you can probably just sort their names with the right comparator and remove all but the last one. If you want to be really robust you'll need to read the bundle metadata to find out about its version number.

If you want to run your tool automatically at regular intervals you could register an OSGi EventHook to detect when new bundles are installed, and trigger a cleanup run when that happens.

Sorry if this sounds a bit complicated - but again leftover bundle files are not really problematic.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I was hoping that there would be a more straightforward way to remove the old versions, but I think your suggestion is solid. Your comment that the Apache Sling OSGI installer selects the latest version based on the OSGi version header made me think that the problem would also be solved if the filename of the bundles would not contain the version number, but I am not sure whether there is a way to remove the version number from the filename while keeping it in the OSGi header using the Maven Bundle Plugin.

Comment: You are right that using the same filename for all versions would solve the purge problem, but you might have transient issues while replacing the file, I'm not sure if the installer handles that cleanly. If you want to play with filenames the best might be to use alternating filenames (bundleA, bundleB and then back to A) so you'd have only one leftover and no transient issues.

Comment: In our development builds we don't change the filenames of our bundles. They always contain the same (x.x.x-SNAPSHOT) release number. We didn't have any problems with that so far, so I guess the installer is able to handle that situation.

Comment: What if you want to install an old version, eg rolling back to an earlier release?

Comment: Removing the later versions should do that.

Answer (score 0):

use curl command to delete the specific bundle version.

```
curl -u admin:admin -daction=uninstall http://localhost:4505/system/console/bundles/"name of bundle"
```

Edit: Removed purging  as that was not applicable to the osgi bundle.

Comment: I don't think the question has anything to do with the JCR VersionManager, it is about OSGi bundle versions, not JCR node versions.

Comment: @BertrandDelacretaz actually i was thinking that this bundle will be installed as a jcr node so we can purge that using purging but i am unable to get the version number so second part is not working. what we can do is create a new scheduler which we can schedule to run after a specific interval. in this scheduler we will delete the old nodes from the install folder and keep the latest version for all bundles using a pattermather or using the split function to extract the numeric vale from the version number.

Comment: any way curl part is working fine we can use curl to delete the old version

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping I could remove the old versions automatically as part of the Maven build. Issuing a HTTP request to delete a specific file would not be a big problem I guess, but figuring out which specific files to delete would presumably be the bigger problem.

Comment: you can set up a uninstall goal in your maven build in which you can uninstall the previous version.refer to [this](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/sling.html)